# How delete optgroup element from dropdown in Yii2 form

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I am generating a DropDownList element in Yii2 with ActiveForm.
My code is:

```
$form->field($model, 'job_type_id')
     ->dropDownList([ArrayHelper::map(JobsTypes::find()->all(), 'id', 'type_name' )])
     ->label('Job type')
```

But this generates the following HTML code:

```
<select name="Jobs[job_type_id]" class="form-control" id="jobs-job_type_id">
<optgroup label="0">
<option value="1">Sites</option>
<option value="2">Marketing</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Why is there an *optgroup* element? This is not required. How do I delete this element from code?

When using

```
Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'id', ...);
```

the Html is generated correctly, but this element doesn't have a `label()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting an optgroup is because you have wrapped the `ArrayHelper::map...` in an array and as such are passing in an array of arrays into the dropdown. As such the parameter being passed into the dropdown is of the form:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        1 => "Sites",
        2 => "Marketing",
        ...
    )
)
```

If nested arrays are passed into [`dropDownList`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeDropDownList%28%29-detail), the sub arrays are treated as an optgroup with the corresponding keys of the outer array as the opt-group labels. The optgroup `label` is `0` since the result of `ArrayHelper::map()` is the first element of the array.

To fix this pass the `ArrayHelper::map...` without the square brackets around it:

```
$form->field($model, 'job_type_id')
     ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(JobsTypes::find()->all(), 'id', 'type_name' ))
```

Comment: Your welcome. You should mark this as the answer by clicking the green tick.